# Virtualenv not executable

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I installed virtualenv to

```
$HOME/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

i.e.

```
pip install virtualenv
```

gives me:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in ./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages)
```

However, there is no executable virtualenv there - there are only

```
virtualenv.py
virtualenv-1.11.6.dist-info
virtualenv.pyc
virtualenv_support
```

What is going on?

```
which virtualenv
```

returns

```
virtualenv: Command not found.
```

Is there a way for me to get the executable?

Comment: Is there a `./python/bin`? Is it on your path?

Comment: What does `which pip` tell you about where `pip` is installed?

Comment: 'which pip'
gives me /home/wilcai/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip

Comment: echo $PATH gives:
/home/wilcai/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/home/wilcai/python/Python-2.7.2:/home/wilcai/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages://home/wilcai/python/Python-2.7.2://usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lpp/mmfs/bin:/usr/local/pbs/default/bin

Comment: and my $PYTHONPATH is /home/wilcai/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
I'm on a remote server so I had to make a local installation of python

Comment: Somewhat surprised to find `pip` the script installed in your `site-packages`. Is there no `/home/wilcai/python/bin` here?

Comment: There is - is that where pip is supposed to go?

Comment: I'd expect it to go there, yes. What is *in* that directory now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57123/discussion-between-wcai-and-martijn-pieters).